# How to use one table (ods) file as a base for another table file?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have an accounting ledger table (`.ods`) file which should be the base for other table files.

This table file should be the base for other table files such as:

- 2023.ods
- 2024.ods
- 2025.ods

These are year files each of which contains a ledger for a given year.

---

Of course, each year I could just copy-paste the template ledger file and rename the copied file, to, say, 2023.ods but I wonder if it bears any benefits to "export" or "include" the template file into such new files (such as 2023.ods).

So, my problem is to determine between mere copy-pasting each new year to exporting/including each new year.

I don't seek a primarily opinion based answer but more of a standardization-based prons and cons answer also explaining what to do and how to do it.

Comment: Please see [*What should I do if no one answers my question?*](https://superuser.com/help/no-one-answers) and restrain yourself from littering the question. Edits that improve the question are welcome.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I find the linked page isn't helpful and I don't think that "restrain" is the right word here. There should be a bump mechanic used in "hot" sites. You are welcome to suggest this in the network Meta.

Comment: not helpful* that is.

Comment: The [Community user](https://superuser.com/users/-1/community) randomly pokes old unanswered questions every hour so they get some attention. This is the mechanism.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thank you, sadly this was not mentioned in the document you have referred me to...